# When doing survival analysis in R, how to get the time before death of a patient?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm new to survival analysis, and really need your help. Thank you so much!

I want to analyze：

1. how soon will a patient die in days?
2. whats the probability for the patient to die?

Are these two the possible outcomes of survival analysis in R?

I tried the following code, and couldn't understand the summary results:

```
library(survival)
addicts <- read.table("ADDICTS.txt", T)
names(addicts) <- c('id', 'clinic', 'status', 'survt','prison','dose')

Surv(addicts$survt, addicts$status ==1)

y <- Surv(addicts$survt, addicts$status ==1)
kmfit1 <- survfit(y~1)
summary(kmfit1)
plot(kmfit1)

coxmodel <- coxph(y~prison + dose + clinic, data = addicts)
summary(coxmodel)
```

results:

[image]

Which line are the two things I want? or when a new patients comes in, how to get that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Display a graph using values from `time` as values for the x-axis, and values of `survival` for the y-axis.  You will see a decreasing curve.  You will not be able to answer questions for a specific individual (your two questions), but about the group.  For example, at what time does half the population remain (look at the x value corresponding to y=0,5).  For questions relating to "when a patient comes in", in survival analysis, all persons start at time 0 (relative time), even if this does not represent the same day.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Tahnk you. Good to know.